# Comprobar si el scanner esta vacio

Tags: java, scanner

buenas necesito que me detecte que si no escribo nada en el scanner y le doy a enter sin mas me salte este mensaje indicando que debo escribir algo.

Como si se tratase de un campo obligatorio pero no se porque no me salta con esto.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String nombreIntroducido = "";
    
        System.out.println("Introduzca nombre de empleado");
        nombreIntroducido = scanner.next();

        if(nombreIntroducido.isEmpty()) { 
            System.out.println("Escribe algo porfavor");
        }else {
            nombreIntroducido = scanner.next();
        }
}
```

Comment: que te detecte como? indefinidamente? Eso se puede con un while..

Comment: tiene que ser como cuando en un formulario que hay datos con campos obligatorios, si quieres darle al enter te recuerde que tienes que escribir algo, y vuelva a saltar el scanner, no se si me explico

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es algo como esto lo que estas buscando??

El programa no te dejara pasar y te preguntara por el nombre del empleado infinitamente si esta vacio el nombre.

Esto es por el while que controla si el nombre viene vacio continuara haciendo el bucle

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Introduzca nombre de empleado");
      String nombreIntroducido = "";

      while(nombreIntroducido.isEmpty())
      {
        nombreIntroducido = scanner.nextLine();

        if(nombreIntroducido.isEmpty() || nombreIntroducido.isBlank()) { 
            System.out.println("Escribe algo porfavor");
        }
      }
      System.out.println(nombreIntroducido);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Christian porque dices? lo probe y si pide, imprime "Escribe algo porfavor" si se entra un texto vacio

Comment: lo siento no había visto el `nextLine` >_< (las puras letras blancas confunden mucho)

Comment: xD no hay problema

Comment: El codigo de Cmbuffa es tal cual lo que necesitaba saber. Intente con un do while pero no me salia pero asi que es mas sencillo si. Muchas gracias ^^

Comment: @Cmbuffa Utilizando solo `.isEmpty()`, en caso de que se introduzcan espacios en blanco, se detectará que se ha escrito en el Scanner. Sería mejor añadir un `OR` en la sentencia `if`. De esta forma, si se introducen 4 espacios en blanco (o más o menos), no se detectará como que se ha escrito en el Scanner! `Simplemente es un apunte!`. Un Saludo!

Comment: @Alexci gracias! aprobe tu edicion

Comment: @Cmbuffa No es nada, es simplemente por ponernos "estrictos", de todas formas tu respuesta ya era más que útil!

Answer (score 1):

Hola espero tambien te sirva esto, ingresa al bucle a traves del "do" y se mantiene esperando a que el string ingresado no sea vacio, debido a la condicion del "while".

```
System.out.println("Introduzca nombre de empleado");
    do {
        nombreIntroducido = scanner.nextLine();
    } while (nombreIntroducido.isEmpty());
```